# Git merge Spaghetti - How to fix it?

Tags: git

It seems like we've done a bit of merge "spaghetti" with git. 
[image]

We are new to this and would basically like to have the following branches

```
Master  A - B - C 
            __//
Core       /   A - B - C - D - E - F  
          |
iPhone    A - B - C
```

But it seems like at some point we merged master into core, then core back to master, then master back to core .. not sure what / how / why did this happen .. but I would love some help to put this back on track without messing around too much !

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify: the A-B-C on Master is only slightly related to the commits A-B-C-D-E-F on Core, and it is not clear whether any of those are more than ancestrally related to A-B-C on iPhone...Maybe you should rename the Core commits H-I-J-K-L-M and the iPhone commits T-U-V.  Also, the slash from Master/C to Core/A is puzzling; is the backwards motion intentional?  Is there actually a problem with the iPhone branch?  If you actually want Master/A and Core/A and iPhone/A to be the same commit, what about the /B commits?  And how do the desired dozen commits relate to the 23 commits shown?

Comment: So we wanted to have 3 branches, a Master one that has only the code ready to be used. an iPhone branch where we store the iphone development, and ad core branch where we store the core of the application. Whenever we are ready to release the code, we merge both branch with the master in order to get a new version on the master. Maybe it doesn't make sense to do it that way, I am just learning git. ! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to linearize the "Core" branch? Why not just `git rebase` it ?

```
Master  A - B - C 
            __//
Core       /   D - E - F - G - H - I
          |
iPhone    J - K - L


git checkout core
git rebase C   [where "C" is the sha1 of C]
```

If you see any conflict, do a `git rebase --abort` to back to previous state.

Comment: ah ! I never heard of rebase. Will look into this .

Comment: You may need to add `--force` when pushing to github.  You need that for rewriting the history.

Comment: And since you're talking about `push -f`, be sure and read the section "recovering from upstream rebase" of the git-rebase man page so you understand what others will have to do to recover.